# JQuery if span value = 0 change color

Tags: jquery, css, class, colors, html

I am currently trying to change the value of a span tag if it is 0. I was using:

```
$('span.number:contains("0")').css('color', '#C1C1C1');
```

The only problem with this is that if the number is 50 it still changes it. Is there a way to change the color of this tag/class if it is ONLY 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter for a exact text match because :contains will return partial matches also

```
$('span.number').filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()) == '0'
}).css('color', '#C1C1C1');
```

Answer (score 1):

Not with a selector, but you can check the text itself:

```
$("span.number").text(function (_, text) {
    if ("0" === text) {
        this.style.color = "#C1C1C1";
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q4mHL/

Answer (score 0):

You could just check it's value instead of trying a one-liner.

```
var val = $("span.number").text(),
spanNumber = $("span.number");
if (val === '0') {
    spanNumber.css('color', '#c1c1c1');
}
```

Comment: `.val` will not return anything because the span has no `value` property

Answer (score 0):

If you try with

```
If ($('span.number').html () == '0'){
    $(this).css('color', '#C1C1C1');
}
```